# Validate a currency string

Tags: c#

Please see the code below:

```
public bool IsValidateInputSuceeded(string EnteredCost, string EnteredPaymentReceived, out decimal Cost, out decimal PaymentReceived)
{
    bool ValidateInputSuceeded = true;

    EnteredCost= EnteredCost.Substring(EnteredCost.IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray()));
    EnteredPaymentReceived = EnteredPaymentReceived.Substring(EnteredPaymentReceived.IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray()));

    if ((Decimal.TryParse(EnteredCost.Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ""), out Cost)) == false)
    {
        ValidateInputSuceeded = false;
    }

    if ((Decimal.TryParse(EnteredPaymentReceived.Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ""), out PaymentReceived)) == false)
    {
        ValidateInputSuceeded = false;
    }

    if (ValidateInputSuceeded == false)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (EnteredCost.IndexOf(" ") > 0|| EnteredPaymentReceived.IndexOf(" ") > 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (EnteredCost[EnteredCost.Length-1] =='.' || EnteredCost[EnteredCost.Length - 2] == '.' || EnteredPaymentReceived[EnteredPaymentReceived.Length - 1]=='.' || EnteredPaymentReceived[EnteredPaymentReceived.Length - 2] == '.')
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (EnteredCost.IndexOf(".") == -1 || EnteredPaymentReceived.IndexOf(".")==-1)
    {
        return false;
    }


    return true;
}
```

EnteredCost and EnteredPaymentReceived are input parameters from MaskedTextBoxs'(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) both with an input mask of: £999,999.00.  For example, a value of one of them could be: "£   ,  3.22" (without quotes) as an input parameter into the function.

There are two string variables: EnteredCost and PaymentReceived. Should these variables be StringBuilders instead of Strings? The reason I ask is because there are a log of string manipulations going on e.g. using the REPLACE function and the indexOfAny function, which returns more strings.

Comment: Please take a moment to rewrite the title and write what your code is doing and not your concerns about it. If you are not sure how to do it see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) also please explain the code _a little bit more_.

Comment: StringBuilder helps with concatenation, not replace or index of. Describing the desired validation method might help with suggesting a faster/cleaner approach.

Comment: @D. Jurcau , I have edited the question with more detail.  Does that help?

Comment: @t3chb0t, I have edited the question.  Does that help?

Comment: Yep, I like it much better now however the title still needs to bo improved. It's validating a payment string so maybe try to write something about it like validating payment string has some format etc. You know better what the method does. The title should reflect this.

Comment: @t3chb0t, I have edited the question.  Are you able to answer? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if I'm able to answer yet but the question looks fine now so it's worth upvoting, good job improving it ;-)

Comment: Using a regular expression can reduce your validation to one line of code.

Comment: @D. Jurcau, I will look into this.  Are you able to provide the line?

Comment: If you use a Label for the currency symbol and a NumericUpDown control for the value, you eliminate any extra validation completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

> `EnteredCost` and `EnteredPaymentReceived` are input parameters from `MaskedTextBox`

and a `MaskedTextBox`

> Uses a mask to distinguish between proper and improper user input.

then the validation is not necessary because all it does is to check whether the strings contain numeric data and a dot `.` as a separator. The `MaskedTextBox`s alredy do that so why are you validating their input again?

Comment: The text can appear like this: "   ,   9.52", which cannot be casted into a decimal or like this: "£   ,   9,5 " (space on the end) or like this: "£   ,   9. 2" (second to last character is a space).  Therefore I believe validation is necessary?

Comment: @w0051977 you could set the `TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals` so the `Text` property will give you a clean int, you can then easily parse it and multiply with `0.01` and the the actuall value (assuming the mask is something like `£ 0.00`.

Comment: @w0051977 _The text can appear like this: " , 9.52", [..] or like this: "£ , 9,5 [..] or like this: "£ , 9. 2"_ how so? If it's a masked-text-box then why are so many formats allowed? It doesn't make sense. Didn't you set the `Mask` property? If you didn't then this control hasn't any advantage over an ordinary text-box and this would explain why the manual validation.

Comment: the mask is: £999,999.00.  This means someone can enter: £ , 9. 2, doesn't it?

Comment: @w0051977 that's true but then the input will still be valid because the mask already validates the input. What you are asking is rather how to parse this input as a decimal. I'm pretty sure your validation method never returns a `false` because the string is always valid.

Comment: the values in my first comment will cause the validation to fail.  The values will be parsed into decimals, however 50p could be interpreted as £50.  Like you; I though a mask would handle all this.  Am I missing something key?

Comment: @w0051977 when I use the `Mask = "£999,999.00"` it's not possible to enter anything else but a digit or a space so I don't understand where the `50p` should come from. The user shouldn't even be able to use the _P_ or any other letter. It's also not possible to type any separators either.

Comment: the TryParse should never fail.  However, I believe all the other validation is needed.